# ITunes Connect - > is it possible to configure the duration of Beta testing for internal tester

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I understand from apple developer site that app will be available for Beta testing for internal Tester for a period of 31 days. I would like to know

a. Is it possible to configure the testing duration or it will by default be 31 days. 
b. Once the app is installed in the internal tester device and then i try to Turn OFF "TestFlight Beta testing " what will happen. Whether the existing app on the internal tester device will run or not.

Any input on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A. You cannot change the 31 day value

B. The app will continue running on the tester's phone but he can no longer install it from the Testflight app. Note that after 31 days the app will show an expiration alertView at launch.

Comment: This would mean that it will prevent further installation of new versions of the app uploaded.

Comment: Beta installations yes

Answer (score 1):

For your question B, here is what Apple said

[image]